# Select 1+ most recent rows

Tags: sql, select, oracle11g

Given is a table with articles. The following exemplary table contains one article in different variations:

```
ID     ARTICLE_NUMBER   STORE_ID   COUNTRY   TYPE   VALID_FROM
----------------------------------------------------------------
100    1                22         DE        A      2015-11-01
101    1                22         DE        A      2015-11-02
102    1                22         DE        A      2015-11-03
103    1                22         DE        A      2015-11-04
104    1                22         DE        B      2015-11-10
105    1                22         DE        B      2015-11-11
106    1                22         DE        B      2015-11-11
```

What I need is a query which returns just the **ID** of the article with

- article_number = 1 AND
- store_id = 22 AND
- country = 'DE' AND
- the latest valid_from timestamp.

So far, the query should return ID = 105 or 106 (both have the same valid_from date, but I want only the one or the other in my result, no matter which, but not both). **AND:** because there are two types for this article (A + B), I also need ID = 103 in my result set.

How must the query look like?

Answer (score 1):

You could try the HAVING parameter in your filter and selecting MAX(ID)

Or with a subselect:

```
SELECT [Type],(SELECT TOP(1) ID from dbo.articles S WHERE S.[Type] = A.Type AND S.Valid_From = MAX(A.Valid_From))
FROM dbo.articles A
WHERE 
    ARTICLE_NUMBER = 1
    AND STORE_ID = 22
    AND Country = 'DE'
    -- AND Valid_FROM = (SELECT MAX(VALID_FROM) FROM dbo.articles)
GROUP BY [Type]
```